# Regular Expression to match pattern once or more with no partial matches

Tags: regex, grep

Better explained with examples:

1. **HHH**
2. **HHHH**
3. **HHHBBHHH**
4. **HHHBH**
5. **BB**
6. **HHBH**

I need to come up with a regexp that matches only 3 H's or a multiple of 3 H's (so 6, 9, 12, ... H's are ok as well) and 5 H's are **not** ok. And if possible I don't want to use Perl regexps.

So for the input above the regexp would match (1), (3) and (6) only.
I'm just starting with regular expressions here so I don't exactly know how I'm supposed to approach this.

**edit**
Just to clear something up:, an H can only be in one group of 3 H's. The group of 3 H's might be HHH or HHBH.
That's why in example 2 above it is not a match because the last H is not in a group of 3 H's. And you can't take the last 3 H's in a group because the middle 2 H's have already been inside a group before.

Comment: Do you mean it must contain in total a multiple of 3 H's? Or is any H considered to be in a group of H's with size of a multiple of 3?

Comment: Why is (3) to be selected and (4) to be excluded?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Because (4) ends with a single H.

Comment: So, if H appears at all, it must be in a triplets...OK.  And presumably 'HHHxxHHHyyHHHzzHHHppHHH' should be OK, but 'HHHxxHHHyyHHHzzHHHppHH' (one less H at the end) should be rejected?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes that's right but bear in mind that the H's might not be in triplets they could be separated, but in total the H's count is a multiple of 3.

Comment: So 'HxHyH' is OK, but 'aHbHHcH' is not because there are 4 H's in total.  Ouch!  This set of requirements is not a beginner's regular expression.

Comment: yes you are both right. I added a 6th example to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^([^H]*H[^H]*H[^H]*H[^H]*)+$
```

It matches any string which contains in total 3 H or any multiple of 3. In between there might be any other character.

Explanation:

```
^              begin of string
(              start of group
  [^H]*H       any string of characters (or none) not including 'H' plus a single 'H'
  [^H]*H       any string of characters (or none) not including 'H' plus a single 'H'
  [^H]*H       any string of characters (or none) not including 'H' plus a single 'H'
  [^H]*        any string of characters (or none) which is not 'H'
)+             containing the group once or twice or ...
$              end of string
```

By repeating the subpattern `[^H]*H` three times we make sure that there are indeed 3 `H` included, `[^H]*` allows any separating characters.

*Note: use either `egrep` or run grep with additional argument `-E`.*

Comment: I don't think this will work with `grep` (and neither will the others).

Comment: @FelixKling: `egrep` will handle it, which is also `grep -E`.

Comment: @Jonathan: Ok, but this has to be mentioned.

Comment: @FelixKling Added a note saying such.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it works! Would you please explain a bit however? I understand the syntax but the pattern iteself doesn't make much sense to me. And What makes a regular expression extended or not extended (so I use grep -E)?

Answer (score 2):

Use this to match a multiple of 3 H's:

```
(H{3})+
```

Here is a complete regex for your examples:

```
^(H{3})+B*(H{3})*$
```

Edit: It looks like you need to count non-consecutive H's. In that case:

```
^(([^H]*H){3})+[^H]*$
```

That should match any string with a multiple of 3 H's.

Answer (score 2):

Given the requirement that H's can be arbitrarily interleaved with non-H's, but that the total number of H's must be a non-zero multiple of 3 (so XXX, containing no H's, is not a match), then the total regular expression is anything but trivial.  This is not a beginner's regular expression.

I'm going to assume that the dialect of regular expression treats `{}` and `()` as metacharacters for counting and grouping, and includes `+` for one-or-more.  If you're using a regular expression system that has a different requirement (`\{\}`, for example) then adjust accordingly.

You need the regex to match the whole string, so there are no stray H's allowed.  So, it must start with `^` and end with `$`.  You need to allow an arbitrary number of non-H's at front and back.  The H's may be separated by an arbitrary number of non-H's.  That leads to:

```
^([^H]*H[^H]*H[^H]*H)+[^H]*$
```

Ouch; that is hard to read!  It says the line must consist of 1 or more (`+`) groups of an arbitrary number of non-H's followed by an H, an arbitrary number of non-H's, another H, an arbitrary number of non-H's and a third H; all of which can be followed by an arbitrary number of non-H's.

Using the `{}` for counting:

```
^(([^H]*H){3})+[^H]*$
```

That's still hard to read.  Note that my description said "arbitrary number of non-H's at front and back", but I only use the `[^H]*` at the back; that's because the repeating pattern allows an arbitrary number of non-H's at the front anyway so there's no need to repeat that fragment.

Comment: Thank you sir for the explanation, however I found Howard's explanation easier to follow